# How to know what's happening with a patch I submitted for Blender

Tags: source-code

About three months ago, I submitted a proposed patch for changing how the ParticleInstance modifier works in Blender (https://developer.blender.org/D9100).  Since then, there has been no feedback.  I have no idea if this will be reviewed and acted on or if it will just be ignored.  I feel this is a very useful feature and would like to see it incorporated into the Blender program so that I may be able to use it in the future.

Comment: This site is not related to the blender institute, nor has any connection to the developers. You might want to follow up on the same place where you posted your proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid to nudge the developers if it's been a while. You could do that on https://blender.chat in the `#blender-coders` channel, or by mentioning the assigned reviewer in the patch comments.